# Ember's volatile and templates

Tags: ember.js

I have a property `mood` which is part of the interface for a component. Behind the scenes I have a computed property called `_mood`:

```
const { computed, typeOf } = Ember;
_mood: computed('mood','A','B','C' function() {
  let mood = this.get('mood');
  if (typeOf(mood) === 'function') {
    mood = mood(this);
  }
  return !mood || mood === 'default' ? '' : `mood-${mood}`;
}).volatile(),
```

I have a situation where with the `volatile()` that hangs of of Ember's **computed** object resolves all non DOM unit tests successfully but for some reason it is *not* triggering the template to update the DOM under any circumstance. It should, at the very least, update if any of properties being watched change (in this case `['mood','A', 'B', 'C']`) change. Because it is volatile (aka, doesn't cache results) the new results would show up in a template if the template knew to re-render the component but for some reason it doesn't.

If I remove the `volatile()` tag it works fine for static/scalar values but if mood is a function then the result is cached and therefore it only works once (not a working solution for this problem).

How do I get the best of both worlds?

Comment: Doesn't that `on('init')` at the beginning mean the property is only computed at initialization time? You're using a different syntax for CPs than I'm used to seeing, so I may be mis-reading.

Comment: Because I'm developing an addon I am not using function prototypes; I have also used a bit of a shortcut with `on` and `computed` being fully qualified as `Ember.on` and `Ember.computed`. That said ... to your original statement ... the `on('init', ` lead-in just ensures that it is run on the init event but the `computed( ... )` part ensures it is checked whenever the stated properties are updated.

Comment: I will add a few adjustments to make things clearer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure why the `volatile()` method is turning off updates to templates. This *might* be a real bug but in terms of solving my problem the important thing to recognise was that the **volatile** approach was never the best approach.

Instead the important thing to ensure is that when `mood` comes in as a *function* that the function's dependencies are included in the CP's dependencies. So, for instance, if `mood` is passed the following function:

```
mood: function(context) {
   return context.title === 'Monkeys' ? 'happy' : 'sad'; 
}
```

For this function to evaluate effectively -- and more importantly to trigger a re-evaluation at the right time -- the `title` property must be part of the computed property. Hopefully that's straight forward as to *why* but here's *how* I thought I might accommodated this:

```
_moodDependencies: ['title','subHeading','style'],
_mood: computed('mood','size','_moodDependencies', function() {
  let mood = this.get('mood');
  console.log('mood is: %o', mood);
  if (typeOf(mood) === 'function') {
    run( ()=> {
      mood = mood(this);
    });
  }
  return !mood || mood === 'default' ? '' : `mood-${mood}`;
}),
```

That's better, as it allows at build time for a static set of properties to be defined per component (the `_mood` CP for me is part of a mixin used by a few components). Unfortunately this doesn't yet work completely as the it apparently doesn't unpack/destructure the `_moodDependencies`.

I'll get this sorted and update this unless someone else beats me to the punch.